# Batch file does not continue after FOR /f

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

The batch file below runs through the :RUNRULES section, executes the DO for every file in folder and after the loop executes things get funky. The IF never gets executed.

The ECHO is executed, but the echo command is not echoed, as if ECHO OFF was active. The IF is also not echoed.

```
::@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEEXTENSIONS

SET S1=Server1
SET S2=Server2
SET DATABASE=DbName
SET SCRIPT=folder\sqlscript.sql

:S1
ECHO Running rules in S1
SET SERVER=%S1%
GOTO RUNRULES

:S2
ECHO Running rules in S2
SET SERVER=%S2%
GOTO RUNRULES

:RUNRULES
SET OUTPUTFILE=%SERVER%_folder.csv
COPY NUL %OUTPUTFILE% 
FOR /f %%f IN ('dir /b /on folder') DO (
    IF EXIST results.csv DEL /Q results.csv 
    CALL RunRule "%SERVER%" "%DATABASE%" "folder\%%f" "results.csv"
    TYPE results.csv >>%OUTPUTFILE%
)

ECHO Past the FOR loop
IF %SERVER%==%S1% GOTO S2
```

Comment: You are calling an external script called `RunRule` which might cause the problem; hard to tell since you do not share it...

Comment: Are you certain that `dir /b /on folder` actually produces anything? If not, the for will never be entered and thus what's inside that loop will never run.

Comment: RunRule is a batch file and we know it returns because it runs for every file in the folder (yes, Ken, it produces a bare list of files in the folder sorted by name). But, yes, you're right in that ECHO OFF in that batch file is what turns off the ECHO. Duh me.

Comment: You were correct, aschipfl, the RunRule batch file was also using SERVER environment variable and since it is passed with double quotes, the variable got reset to "S1" and the IF was comparing "S1"==S1. If you can post an answer, I'll close this question.

Comment: You should get into the habit of using the TOKENS and DELIMS options with the FOR /F command.

Comment: @Metaphor, posting an answer does not make any sense, unless you include the relevant (failing) portion of `RunRule.bat` in your question... Note that you can even post an answer yourself -- after having [edited](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/39780965/edit) your question accordingly, of course...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The RunRule is a batch file that includes an ECHO OFF and sets the environment variable SERVER to another value, adding quotes to the value of SERVER. The IF compares the new value of SERVER to the value it was originally set to and does not execute because they are not equal.